# How to unbind a key binding

Tags: visual-studio-2012, key-bindings

Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012, fresh install, "Visual C++ developer" keyboard scheme.

Each time I press Ctrl+Shift+1 or Ctrl+Shift+2 (which is set up so switch between input languages), visual studio opens some new windows.

How do I unbind the keys?

I don't even know which command they are bound to. Google founds "Navigates to the next definition, declaration, or reference of an item". OK, I've tried typing both "definition", "declaration", and "reference" into "show commands containing:" box but I was unable to find any command bound to Ctrl+Shift+1/2 combination.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Click Tools, Options, Environment, Keyboard.
2. Enter the keys in the Press shortcut keys box to find out what they're bound to
3. Enter part of that name in the upper filter box, then select the command
4. Click Remove